# Proper component where to encrypt in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am a newbie just starting out with Spring MVC (unfortunately, the documentation doesn't help me much), and I am still scratching my head on where to use the Jasypt PasswordEncrypter to encrypt the password received through the registration form. Is it a bad practice to do it directly in the User model password setter or should I use a service? Also, I believe this can be integrated with Spring Security to have the encryptor used for auth as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Authentication**

Use authenticationProvider` to encode the password post authentication

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**On User Creation**

Encode in `userService`

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

then

```
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
```

Source: [Registration with Spring Security – Password Encoding](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt)

[Another example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/)

Also, make sure to define the input for the password to be secured

Comment: Yes, you will need a user controller for actions like registering.  Check http://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security